# Texture painting looks pixelated no matter the size of image.

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-painting

I have a large path system intended for game engine. The pathway is broken up into 4 separate models.

Iv'e unwrapped one piece onto a 2048x1024 image and tried painting various 2048x2048 concrete textures onto it but they always come out really pixelated. 
I try painting tiled texture but its very bad looking.

My goal is to have one layer of the tiled concrete texture, and one layer of details like cracks and blemishes and such, all on one texture.

Zooming in and out of painting seems to change the size of the image as I paint and its very frustrating. I havent gotten it to look like its correct resolution once.

is there a better way to do this? thanks.

[image: Uvs]

[image: texture]

[image: mesh]

Answer (score 1):

Your mapping could be improved, as you really should take advantage of a tileable texture for something like a path. Part of your question:

> Iv'e unwrapped one piece onto **a 2048x1024** image and tried painting various **2048x2048** concrete textures onto it but they always come out really **pixelated**. I try painting tiled texture but its very bad looking.

You are using a single image at 2048 x 1024 to try to pump way too many pixels into it - but you only have that one image worth of pixels to do this. If you try to paint them into that, you will get pixelation because your destination image (2048x1024) doesn't have more pixels than the sum of the number of times you are looking to repeat the brush image pixels at full resolution. Better to look at using UV Unwrap - Follow Active and then try to get the main tileable texture to sit appropriately for one face, then the rest will fall in line. You could use a second uv mapping for the second texture to determine dirt, etc.

Comment: Follow active might be what I need. ill get back shortly.

Comment: after changing my image size to 2048x2048 and doing a pretty goo follow active quad unwrap, texture painting is still extremely pixelated and blurry :(

Comment: I tried tiling the texture using cycles nodes, then painting over that on a separate image and that seemed to work but baking it did not work

Comment: I made a video describing the problem and the actual typical approach I take. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fX0Xi7OvLbY